# automating word 2010 to generate docs

Tags: automation, word-2010

the webapp was already done on office2007 and i need to convert it so it'll work in office2010.
i was able to convert the header generator part of the code but i have problem with the body of the doc itself. the code copy the data from a "data" doc and paste it into the generated doc.

```
appword.activewindow.activepane.view.seekview = 0
    'set appsel1 = appword.activewindow.selection
    set appsel1 = appword.window(filepath).selection        -that is the original one
    appdoc1.bookmarks("b1").select
    appword.selection.insertafter("some text")
    appsel1.endkey(6)         -the code stops here
    appword.selection.insertafter("some other text")
```

the iexplorer debuger says ERROR:appsel1 object required. and when i view its data using the iexplorer debugger its data is "empty" instead of "{...}"
can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong
if you need more of the code tell me.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.insertafter.aspx)

> After this method is applied, the selection expands to include the new
>   text.
>
> If you use this method with a selection that refers to an entire
>   paragraph, the text is inserted after the ending paragraph mark (the
>   text will appear at the beginning of the next paragraph). To insert
>   text at the end of a paragraph, determine the ending point and
>   subtract 1 from this location (the paragraph mark is one character).
>
> However, if the selection ends with a paragraph mark that also happens
>   to be the end of the document, Microsoft Word inserts the text before
>   the final paragraph mark rather than creating a new paragraph at the
>   end of the document.
>
> **Also, if the selection is a bookmark, Word inserts the specified
>   text but does not extend the selection or the bookmark to include the
>   new text.**

So I suspect that you still have no selected text.

I wonder if you can do a Selection Collapse(wdCollapseStart)  but that's just a thought.

Comment: its supposed to select all the text in the file it worked at word office 2007